Is not possible to set RabbitMQ policy on Windows Server
I want to set expiration for RabbitMQ message queues.
When I am trying do it with command:
rabbitmqctl.bat set_policy expiry ".*" "{""expires"":432000000}" --apply-to queues

I am getting this error:
Error:
Could not parse JSON document: {error,
                                   {failed_to_decode_json,
                                       <<"{expires:432000000}">>}}

althought I act in accordance with documentation the documentation:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/ttl#queue-ttl-using-policy
Operating system is Windows Server.
Presently I can see that this option is functional for me:
PS C:\scripts> rabbitmqctl.bat set_policy 'expiry' '.*' '{\"expires\":432000000}' --apply-to queues
Setting policy "expiry" for pattern ".*" to "{"expires":432000000}" with priority "0" for vhost "/" ...
PS C:\scripts>


With backslash before quotation mark.

Are you running it from CMD (Command Prompt) or PowerShell? In PowerShell I believe you need to escape the double quote with \", not ""
